# copy the word when searching in emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there any tricky ways to do this: in my text files I have a list of words, one word a line. I want search the word `new-word` in the lists with `C-s`. In order to search it I need to type the word in the `minibuffer`, if the `new-word` isn't exist in the lists, I want to insert it in the list. It seems that I have to retype the word in the `normal buffer`, is there any ways to remember the word that I have just typed in the `minibuffer` and copy it into the `normal buffer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> immediately after <kbd>C-s</kbd> allows you to input the string using the normal minibuffer prompt which supports editing and history of past searches. In that mode you can use the regular buffer commands, such as <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, <kbd>M-w</kbd> and <kbd>C-y</kbd>, to copy contents from the search minibuffer and paste it into a regular buffer, or vice versa.

Comment: my `C-SPC` is bind to the input method of the system, what function does `C-SPC` is bind to in emacs?

Comment: `C-SPC` starts highlighting the region, but these days you can do the same with shift+cursor keys. My answer isn't about any specific binding, but about the fact that, when you press `RET` in isearch, you get all the buffer editing capabilities, including copy-paste.